# Load null data from xml and write null to sql

Tags: c#, sql, xml

i have xml file, and in this file is for example this:

```
<VARIANT2></VARIANT2>
```

I loaded data from xml and after that i write this data into sql. This is command to add value from VARIANT2 to sql database:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@var2", item.VARIANT2);
```

But if the VARIANT2 is emty than into sql table has writen 'blank sign'. It is possible, when is VARIANT2 empty write nothing to sql database? I want had in column NULL value..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if it is null you need to insert it as `DBNull.Value`

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@var2", string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.VARIANT2) ? 
                                                (object)DBNull.Value : item.VARIANT2);
```

Answer (score 3):

As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx) suggests, try this:

```
object value
  = string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.VARIANT2) ? (object)DBNull.Value : item.VARIANT2;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@var2", value);
```